# Issue with rabbitMQ automatic consumer recovery during amazonMQ maintenance window

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit, amazon-mq

We are using the RabbitMQ cluster broker of AmazonMQ service from AWS.
Some consumers of a few queues are not able to recover or get stuck during the maintenance window.

**RabbitMQ Broker engine version:** 3.8.6
**Erlang version:** 23.0.3
**Spring rabbit version:** 1.7.3.RELEASE
**Amqp version:** 4.0.2
**References:**
[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/rabbitmq-broker-architecture-cluster.html](https://stackoverflow.com)
[https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.amqp/spring-rabbit/1.7.3.RELEASE](https://stackoverflow.com)
[https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.rabbitmq/amqp-client/4.0.2](https://stackoverflow.com)

**Errors from amazonMQ service**:

```
2023-06-21 05:50:44.619 [error] <0.12788.1961> Supervisor {<0.12788.1961>,rabbit_channel_sup_sup} had child channel_sup started with rabbit_channel_sup:start_link() at undefined exit with reason shutdown in context shutdown_error
2023-06-21 05:57:59.425 [error] <0.2547.1664> Failed to fetch number of connections in vhost <<"/">> on node {aborted,{no_exists,['tracked_connection_per_vhost_on_node_rabbit@ip-*********.eu-central-1.compute.internal',<<"/">>]}}:
2023-06-21 06:04:37.585 [error] emulator Error in process <0.23288.1664> on node 'rabbit@ip-*******.eu-central-1.compute.internal' with exit value:
2023-06-21 06:06:03.021 [error] <0.17587.0> Failed to fetch number of connections in vhost <<"/">> on node {aborted,{no_exists,['tracked_connection_per_vhost_on_node_rabbit@ip-*********.eu-central-1.compute.internal',<<"/">>]}}:
2023-06-21 06:08:00.691 [error] <0.767.0> ** Generic server <0.767.0> terminating
2023-06-21 06:08:00.711 [info] <0.767.0> [{initial_call,{rabbit_prequeue,init,['Argument__1']}},{pid,<0.767.0>},{registered_name,[]},{error_info,{exit,{{badmatch,-1},[{rabbit_mirror_queue_slave,update_delta,2,[{file,"src/rabbit_mirror_queue_slave.erl"},{line,1058}]},{rabbit_mirror_queue_slave,process_instruction,2,[{file,"src/rabbit_mirror_queue_slave.erl"},{line,991}]},{rabbit_mirror_queue_slave,handle_cast,2,[{file,"src/rabbit_mirror_queue_slave.erl"},{line,299}]},{gen_server2,handle_msg,2,[{file,"src/gen_server2.erl"},{line,1067}]},{proc_lib,wake_up,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,236}]}]},[{gen_server2,terminate,3,[{file,"src/gen_server2.erl"},{line,1183}]},{proc_lib,wake_up,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,236}]}]}},{ancestors,[<0.766.0>,<0.712.0>,<0.696.0>,<0.695.0>,rabbit_vhost_sup_sup,rabbit_sup,<0.269.0>]},{message_queue_len,1},{messages,[{'$gen_cast',{gm,{drop,1711,1,true}}}]},{links,[<0.766.0>,<0.768.0>]},{dictionary,[{{credit_to,<0.18129.0>},198},{{credit_to,<43223.28092.0>},198},{{credit_to,<0.17144.0>},198},{{credit_to,<0.16646.0>},198},{{credit_to,<43223.8144.1>},198},{{credit_to,<0.6344.0>},198},{{credit_to,<43223.13766.1>},198},{{credit_to,<43223.815.1>},198},{{credit_to,<0.9025.0>},198},{{credit_to,<0.8021.0>},198},{{credit_to,<0.25557.0>},198},{{credit_to,<0.25827.0>},198},{{credit_to,<43223.14803.1>},198},{{credit_to,<0.26234.0>},198},{{credit_to,<43223.12736.1>},198},{{credit_to,<0.26367.0>},198},{credit_flow_default_credit,{400,200}},{{credit_to,<0.17881.0>},198},{{credit_to,<43223.137.1>},198},{{credit_to,<43223.10561.1>},198},{{credit_to,<43223.15193.1>},198},{{credit_to,<0.15384.0>},198},{{credit_to,<43223.28435.0>},198},{{credit_to,<43223.32132.0>},198},{{credit_to,<43223.13123.1>},198},{{credit_to,<0.9912.0>},198},{{credit_to,<43223.1404.1>},198},{{credit_to,<43223.10332.1>},198},{{credit_to,<43223.6767.1>},198},{{credit_to,<43223.28750.0>},198},{{credit_to,<0.19857.0>},198},{{credit_to,<43223.26489.0>},198},{{credit_to,<0.10940.0>},198},{{credit_to,<0.7810.0>},198},{{credit_to,<0.7475.0>},198},{{credit_to,<43223.12334.1>},...},...]},...], [{neighbour,[{pid,<0.768.0>},{registered_name,[]},{initial_call,{gm,init,['Argument__1']}},{current_function,{gen_server2,process_next_msg,1}},{ancestors,[<0.767.0>,<0.766.0>,<0.712.0>,<0.696.0>,<0.695.0>,rabbit_vhost_sup_sup,rabbit_sup,<0.269.0>]},{message_queue_len,0},{links,[<0.767.0>]},{trap_exit,false},{status,waiting},{heap_size,987},{stack_size,10},{reductions,1408728},{current_stacktrace,[{gen_server2,process_next_msg,1,[{file,"src/gen_server2.erl"},{line,673}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,226}]}]}]}]
2023-06-21 06:08:00.712 [error] <0.767.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.767.0> with 1 neighbours exited with reason: no match of right hand value -1 in rabbit_mirror_queue_slave:update_delta/2 line 1058 in gen_server2:terminate/3 line 1183
2023-06-21 06:08:00.713 [error] <0.766.0> Supervisor {<0.766.0>,rabbit_amqqueue_sup} had child rabbit_amqqueue started with rabbit_prequeue:start_link({amqqueue,{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"remoting.*******.queue">>},true,false,...}, slave, <0.765.0>) at <0.767.0> exit with reason no match of right hand value -1 in rabbit_mirror_queue_slave:update_delta/2 line 1058 in context child_terminated
```

We want to understand more about this error and ways to fix this issue.
What is the reason for this error and why this happens?
Can anyone help us with this?

We expect all the consumers to be recovered during the maintenance window automatically.

Thanks in advance.